# What is the term for fear of getting fired from one's job?

Tags: single-word-requests, phobias

Is there a term for the irrational fear of being fired or laid off from one's job? If so, what is it?

Comment: A general term is [**insecurity**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/insecurity).

Comment: The Victorians, and later amateur psychologists, delighted in inventing "phobias". A search of the internet will give hundreds, maybe thousands, of examples. Save for a few that have made it into "Standard English": the rest are mere ephemera and curiosities that nobody ever uses. The word you are looking for either does not exist or falls into the latter category. Associated with this is a belief that English has a word for everything - it doesn't.

Comment: Post traumatic-stress disorder.

Comment: Using PTSD would be an abuse of the actual definition of the term....but nowadays people seem to use it  to describe even the emotional trauma of a paper cut.

Comment: No; that's PT-S-D.

Answer (score 4):

Official expressions are:

***[Employment insecurity](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-94-007-0753-5_3457):***

> relates to the subjective or objective risk of (involuntary) reduction of welfare coming from employment, most drastically from the loss of employment.

Or

***[Fear of Job Loss:](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-94-007-0753-5_1022)***

> The fear of job loss refers to the felt threat,  stress, and perceived powerlessness due to the possibility of leaving the current job and being not hired in the labor market.  Fear as such generates  anxiety and lowers the well-being of workers and even their dependents.

(link.springer.com)